# Programmatically specify which version of .NET to load

Tags: .net, delphi, winapi, com

My application is a native, non-.NET application.  However, at times it may need to invoke some .NET services through COM.  Sometimes it needs to load a specific version of .NET to accomplish what it needs to do.  (My app uses a COM interface to `System.EnterpriseServices` in order to programmatically register assemblies and install them in the GAC).

Normally, I could use `MyApp.exe.config` ([as explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee518876%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) if this information was known ahead of time and didn't change between runs.

Unfortunately, the specific version of .NET to load will not be known until runtime (and in fact, may change between runs on the same system).  Therefore using `MyApp.exe.config` will not work.

Is there a way for a native application to supply this information to Windows programmatically before it loads .NET?

(Though my application is written in Delphi, this is more of a general Windows question and answers in any language would be welcome)

Comment: So you are using COM-interop to consume .net services? I thought it worked the other way around. (Com-interop only let you consume COM services from a .net app). How are you currently "loading .net"?

Comment: By instantiating the COM interface (in Delphi, by calling CoPublish.Create), .NET is loaded automatically.   The problem is that I don't know how to control which version to instantiate.  By default, .NET 2.0's version is instantiated;  I have no way to tell it to instantiate the 4.0 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to write your own CLR host, instead of relying on the IJW "it just works" .NET feature.

If .NET 4 is installed on the machine, this link describes how to do it: [Loading the Common Language Runtime into a Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01918c6x%28VS.100%29.aspx). With .NET 4, you can even load multiple versions of the CLR side by side in the same process (with restrictions though).

Additional information: [Use CLR4 Hosting API to invoke .NET assembly from native C++](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdnforum/archive/2010/07/09/use-clr4-hosting-api-to-invoke-net-assembly-from-native-c.aspx)